# Finding the midpoints of an ordered list of numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, partitions

Suppose that I have an *ordered* list of numbers.  The numbers in the list may be evenly spaced, but they may not be.  Here are two examples, `list1` and `list2`:

```
list1 = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};
list2 = {0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1};
```

I would like to write a function to determine the midpoints (or "midvalues").  So, I would like to write `fun` such that with the following input I will obtain the following output:

```
fun[list1]
fun[list2]
```

> ```
> {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
> {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95}
> ```

Is there any built-in way to do this in Mathematica 8?  I am looking for a simple method.  I came up with the following, which seems to work fine, but I am afraid I may be overcomplicating it:

```
midpoint[a_, b_] := (a + b)/2
fun[list_List] := Map[Apply[midpoint, #] &, Partition[list, 2, 1]]
```

where

```
fun[list1]
fun[list2]
```

gives

> ```
> {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}
> {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95}
> ```

Do you have any suggestions to make this simpler?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`MovingAverage` will do the job.

```
MovingAverage[list1, 2]
```

(* {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9} *)

```
MovingAverage[list2, 2]
```

(* {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95} *)

Comment: Beat me to it. +1

Answer (score 7):

Since I missed posting `MovingAverage`, here's the manual way:

```
midpoints = Mean @ {Most[#], Rest[#]} &;

midpoints /@ {list1, list2}
```

> ```
> {{0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}, {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95}}
> ```

One could also use [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorrelate.html) which I believe is equivalent to `MovingAverage`:

```
ListCorrelate[{0.5, 0.5}, #] & /@ {list1, list2}
```

> ```
> {{0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}, {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95}}
> ```

In this case the "manual" way is actually faster (v7 timings):

```
big = Sort @ RandomReal[99, {1500000}];

time = Function[x, First @ Timing @ Do[x, {100}] / 100, HoldAll];

MovingAverage[big, 2]          // time
ListCorrelate[{0.5, 0.5}, big] // time
midpoints[big]                 // time
```

> 0.04508
>
> 0.04586
>
> 0.01529

RK recommended: `{0.5, 0.5}.{Most[#], Rest[#]} &` and this is faster still:

```
{0.5, 0.5}.{Most[#], Rest[#]} &@big // time
```

> 0.01201

---

Here are the timings in V9 ([Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999)'s machine, different base speed).

```
MovingAverage[big, 2] // time
midpoints[big] // time
ListCorrelate[{0.5, 0.5}, big] // time
```

> 0.02919396
>
> 0.04955550
>
> 0.02882864

Comment: +1. As a matter of fact, at some point (that was probably for V8) I have implemented several financial indicators and then compared the speed to the corresponding built-in ones. I was surprised to have found that for some of them, my hand-written ones (compiled to C) were an order of magnitude faster than those built-ins. It may have changed by now, I did not check for a long time.

Comment: In my v9 `MovingAverage` is about twice as fast as your `midpoints`.  `ListCorrelate` is between them. +1 anyway!

Comment: It's appears to be useful to be aware of the timing. +1

Comment: @Michael Good to know `MovingAverage` has been improved.  Would you please append v9 timings for the three methods to this answer?

Comment: Here is the order on my computer: `ListCorrelate` (0.02796875), `MovingAverage` (0.02906250), `midpoints` (0.03531250). V9.0.1 Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Done.  Actually every time I run `ListCorrelate` it gets faster!  The above done with a fresh kernel, though.  (It started tied with yours -- hmm.)

Comment: Similar to `midpoints` would be  `{.5,.5}.{Most@#,Rest@#}&` or `.5(Most@#+Rest@#)&`.

Comment: @Ray The 0.5(a+b) method was obvious, but I didn't consider `Dot`, and it's quite fast.  I'm adding it to my timings.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
midpoints[list_] := Median /@ Partition[list, 2, 1]
```

Comment: FYI: `Mean` appears to be somewhat faster than `Median` here, at least in v7.

Answer (score 2):

First create partitions,

```
par = Partition[list1, 2, 1]
```

Than find `Median` for each sublist as

```
Table[Median[par[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[par]}]
```

gives `{0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}`

Similarly for second list.

Comment: It is simpler to use `/@` as Anon did, but if you prefer `Table` you can use this shorter form: `Table[Median[i], {i, par}]`. (Case #2 [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7925/121)).  Also I don't know why you are using `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Thanks for pointing out,actually I was trying something else and it appended the list, and I carried on with same list. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

In Mathematica 10.2 this can also be achieved with [BlockMap](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html):

```
list1 = {0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1};
list2 = {0, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1};
```

Then:

```
BlockMap[Mean, list1, 2, 1] (* gives: {0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9} *)
```

And:

```
BlockMap[Mean, list2, 2, 1] (* gives: {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95} *)
```

Comment: Finally `PartitionMap[]` is ready for primetime… :)

Answer (score 1):

`MovingAverage` is probably the way to go. But since Suba already beat me to it. Here is another way using pure functions:

```
fun[x_List] := (#1 + #2)/2 & @@@ Partition[x, 2, 1]

fun /@ {list1, list2}
```

> `{{0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}, {0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95}}`

Answer (score 1):

out of the box..

```
Rest@First@ImageData@
       ImageFilter[Mean@First@# &, Image[{#}], {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]  &@ list1
```

ugly as it is i suspect it performs pretty well.. <-Edit wrong its really bad..oh well..

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the 'out of the box' response by george2079, here is another solution that is based on a moving average filter.

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel[y[k] == (u[k] + u[k + 1])/2, y[k], u[k], y[k], k];

OutputResponse[ssm, list1]
(* {{0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9}} *)

OutputResponse[ssm, list2]
(* {{0.15, 0.35, 0.55, 0.8, 0.95}} *)
```

Although the OP was looking for a simple method, I'm thinking this would add to the variety.